# Select all likes from tweet liked by users

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, as you can see in the title, I am looking for how to find all the likes of tweet and then add a users who like to this query without losing the total result of likes.

This is my likes table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
from likes INNER JOIN tweets ON likes.id_tweet = tweets.id 
GROUP BY likes.id_tweet;
```

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_user  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_tweet | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I run this query, I can get all the likes :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
from likes INNER JOIN tweets ON likes.id_tweet = tweets.id 
GROUP BY likes.id_tweet;
```

Like this:

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        4 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        3 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        3 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        1 |
|        3 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        3 |
|        3 |
|        2 |
+----------+
```

and I get all my likes but when i add

```
 where likes.id_users = ...
```

I lost my all likes for just likes of one users likes, concretely i want to recover all the likes of tweets that a users like.

Like this

```
+-----------+----+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
| all likes | id | id_reply | id_poster | id_retweet | text                                                                                                                                         | id_img | tweet_date          |
+-----------+----+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
|         50 |  2 |     NULL |      1714 |       NULL | Mon premier tweet                                                                                                                            |   NULL | 2019-01-23 14:25:24 |
|         43 | 35 |     NULL |      1752 |       NULL | Phasellus id sapien in sapien iaculis congue. Vivamus metus arcu, adipiscing molestie, hendrerit at, vulputate vitae, nisl. Aenean lectus. P |   NULL | 2018-04-29 00:00:00 |
|         22 | 50 |     NULL |      1908 |       NULL | In congue. Etiam justo. Etiam pretium iaculis justo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam faucibus cursus urna. Ut tellus.                |   NULL | 2018-05-23 00:00:00 |
+-----------+----+----------+-----------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: update your question  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: it's ok, I change it.

Comment: While you applying where condition, you using tweets.* in select. Just remove that and see

Comment: It comes down to making the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(likes.[id_user])
from likes INNER JOIN tweets ON likes.id_tweet = tweets.id 
GROUP BY likes.id_tweet;
```

Comment: @jojo92 Then you should post sample data.